# What does 经起 actually mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does `经起` actually mean? Can you please give some sample sentences?

Comment: Can you share the context when you've heard of this term? The phrase doesn't ring any bell to me immediately so I suspect the character might not be the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't see 经起 because it only works with one of the two potential particles --  得 (able to) and 不 (unable to)

经**得**起考验  = **able to** withstand test

经**不**起考验 = **unable to** withstand test

经**得**起风雨 = **able to** withstand hardship/ crisis

经**不**起风雨 = **unable to** withstand hardship/ crisis

from the examples above, we can deduct 经起 means withstand or stand against

However, we don't use 经起 alone without a potential particle

Example:

**经(不)起**考验时就惊惶失措 - Panic when (unable to) **stand against** a test

- 经(v): through; experience
- 起 (verb particle): up; begin to; upon
- 经(不/得) 起 --> (can/cannot) go through --> (can/cannot) withstand/ stand against

Comment: This kind of omission can not be accepted in Mandarin. I think this word is just an error.

Comment: Agree and edited post